# Multiple links to items on same picture

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want to have links on a picture with multiple items(3 in my case, as seen in picture above). Currently I am using position:absolute to map links on each item. This is causing overlap issue. I do not want to use image mapping.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <a href="google.com" style="position: absolute;width: 149px;height: 240px;margin-left: 26%;"></a>
    <a href="yahoo.com" style="margin-left: 35%;position: absolute;width: 167px;height: 240px;"></a>
    <a href="index.com" style="margin-left: 45%;position: absolute;width: 151px;height: 240px;"></a>
    <img src="imagelink" alt="" class="col-md-12">
</div>
```

Comment: You can map areas on the same image using `<map><area></map>` see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).

Comment: Why do you not want to use image mapping? This is exactly the sort of situation image mapping was **designed** for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why image-mapping was designed, but assuming you don't want to make use of it, all you have to do is adjust your `width` and `margin-left` properties so that they don't overlap. Note that your `margin-left` properties are percentage-based, so they will expand based on the size of the parent. As such, you may want to use a fixed value instead, to match the `width`.

The exact values you'll need will differ based on your picture.

Here's a working example, with each link given a border to showcase the click-zone:

```css
a:first-of-type {
  border: 5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 85px;
  height: 140px;
  margin-left: 195px;
}

a:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin-left: calc(195px + 85px + 10px); /* Previous offset + width + borders */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 240px;
}

a:last-of-type {
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-left: calc(290px + 100px + 10px); /* Previous offset + width + borders */
  position: absolute;
  width: 92px;
  height: 240px;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/400">
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `left` and `translate`. See the code below.

```css
a{
background-color:red;
position: absolute;
width:150px;
height:150px;
}
a#fir{
left:0;
}
a#two{
left:50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
}
a#thr{
right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <a id="fir" href="google.com"></a>
    <a id="two" href="yahoo.com"></a>
    <a id="thr" href="index.com"></a>
    <img src="http://www.rokkorfiles.com/photos/360PX.jpg" alt="" class="col-md-12" style="width:100%;display:block;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [image_map](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqbjxa5a/1/)

Click top right corner and middle of that image will redirect you different links.

HTML:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" usemap="#yourmap" border="0">
<map name="yourmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
<area shape="rect" coords="150, 150, 100, 100" href="https://www.yahoo.com/" target="_blank">
</map>
```